# how to allocate space in a struct

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
   {
       char * word = malloc(46 * sizeof(char));
       struct node *left;
       struct node *right;
   } node;
 }
```

but it produces:

```
test2.c:12:16: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
char * word = malloc(46 * sizeof(char));
```

How and where do you allocate the memory for the struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not initialize data members of a structure within its definition in C.

You need to create an object of the structure type and initialize it in its declaration or assign values to its data members separately.

For example

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
   {
       char * word;
       struct node *left;
       struct node *right;
   } node;

   node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
   new_node->word = malloc( 46 * sizeof( char ) );
   strcpy( new_node->word, "Some word or words" );
   new_node->left = NULL;
   new_node->right = NULL;
 }
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
   {
       char * word;
       struct node *left;
       struct node *right;
   } node;

   node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
   new_node->word = malloc( 46 * sizeof( char ) );
   strcpy( new_node->word, "Some word or words" );
   new_node->left = NULL;
   new_node->right = NULL;
   
   puts( new_node->word );
   
   free( new_node->word );
   free( new_node );
 }
```

Its output is

```
Some word or words
```

Pay attention to that you need to define the structure in the file scope if you are going to use it in functions apart from main.

Here is a more meaningful demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char * word;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;

int push_back( list *list, const char *word )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->word = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
        success = new_node->word != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( new_node->word, word );
            new_node->right = NULL;
            new_node->left = list->tail;
                
            if ( list->head == NULL )
            {
                list->head = new_node;
            }
            else
            {
                list->tail->right = new_node;
            }
                
            list->tail = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            free( new_node );
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void free_list( list *list )
{
    while ( list->head )
    {
        node *current = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->right;
        free( current->word );
        free( current );
    }
    
    list->tail = NULL;
}

void display_list( const list *list )
{
    for ( const node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->right )
    {
        printf( "%s -> ", current->word );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void)
{
    list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    push_back( &list, "Hello doubly-linked list!" );
    
    display_list( &list );
    
    free_list( &list );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello doubly-linked list! -> null
```

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: thanks but don't you have to malloc word before you malloc the node? doesn't the memory for the node have to contain memory for the word?

Comment: @DCR Ehm, no? Why?

Comment: @DCR word is a data member of the structure. So you need to allocate an object of the structure to get an access to its data member.

Comment: so when you malloc the node you are only allocating memory to hold the typedef and then you can malloc space for any items needed

Comment: @DCR At first you need to allocate an object of the structure type. After that you can have an access to its data members.